# Getting the value of a element by name in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a problem, I need to obtain the values for html elements by name using Jquery ussually I would do it like this `$("input[name=form_size]).val();` but what if my name attr value looks like this `name="data[referralMedium][referral_id]"` how do I write the JQuery code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put quote marks around it:

```
$("input[name='data[referralMedium][referral_id]']").val();
```

Note that technically the quote marks are *always* required. See the docs for the [attribute equals `[name="value"]` selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

Comment: In addition, you can create your own selector like #id, .class etc. Say for example you want $("--some_name") to return the elements with the name "some_name". This is possible to achieve with a custom selector.

Comment: So this will then also work if($("input[name='data[ReferralMedium][referral_id]'] option:selected").val() == 13){

Comment: @Roland How can an `input` have a descendant `option`?

Comment: @lonesomeday - My Bad, it should be select not input

Answer (score 1):

The name has to be quoted:

```
var element = $('input[name="data[referralMedium][referral_id]"]');
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a good question. What I might do is class each of those inputs and get the value by class rather than by name. I think it's faster, too.

```
  <input type="text" name="data[referralMedium][referral_id]" class="referralMedium_referral_id"/>

  $('.referralMedium_referral_id').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[name="data[referralMedium][referral_id]"]').val();
```